# Custom Post Type URLs - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

Is there a way to define a fixed Custom Post Type URL in Wordpress, meaning a URL that would be independent of the permalinks settings of the website?

I am worried that my plugin might not work properly if the default permalinks settings is activated.

Answer (score 1):

**Here:**

`$permalink` null means it's set **default** permalink.

```
$permalink = get_option('permalink_structure'); 

if($permalink != "")
{   
    echo "<li><a href='".get_bloginfo('url')."/".ltrim (get_option('resolution_base'),'/')."/wallpapers'>LINK</a></li>";
}else{
    echo "<li><a href='".get_bloginfo('url')."/?".ltrim (get_option('resolution_base'),'/')."wallpapers'>LINK</a></li>";
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, I didn't know about the `permalink_structure` option. You rock. That allows me to build a link that will always work and point to my Custom Post Type. 

Is there a way to avoid the URL to change at all? To create a URL that is really independent of the `permalink_structure` setting?

Comment: I think, You can't set this type URL which is  independent of the `permalink_structure` setting in wp. I will try to get this solution.

Comment: Thanks. I looked this up for one hour already, but with no luck so far

Comment: You can create one `function` which is `return` URL(after check permalink structure). And call this function whenever you use url.

Comment: Would that make it a fixed URL? :)

Comment: no, but it's helpful you. Every time you just call this function and get proper url, not check every time.

Comment: I understand, but that would not meet my need unfortunately. I am building a plugin that should display a given URL format (based on a W3C standard). That format is fixed really, and can't evolved with the permalinks settings. Maybe the W3C should have thought about Wordpress permalinks... :)